# UICollectionView with header issue to change y position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I am using `UICollectionView` with header and `UISerach` bar also. Now i am getting issue my header is coming top of search bar. How to change the y position [image]

i want `UISearch` bar then my `collectionview` header. But header not moving down .

Answer (score 0):

Either u accidentally dragged the  header into the search bar or u can change the y value of the header by going into the utilities and clicking the ruler then u will see a section called view and there will be a y and you can change the y value there. if created programmatically then u had to use this line of code.

```
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

that sets the searchbars position and width and height so just change the y value to something higher than the header since the y value goes top to bottom.  And u replace searchBar with whatever you named your search bar

Comment: can you show me screen shot i am not getting .uisearch bar i created via programmatically